# Multi-thread safe buffer in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I am trying to design thread-safe data structure that I cna use as a buffer in my application. Can you please give me comments about this code and what can be improved:

```
#include <deque>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template <typename T>
class Buffer
{
public:
    void add(T num)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
            buffer.push_back(num);
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
            return;
        }
    }
    T remove()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
            cond.wait(locker, [this](){return buffer.size() > 0;});
            T back = buffer.back();
            buffer.pop_back();
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
            return back;
        }
    }
    int size()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        int s = buffer.size();
        locker.unlock();
        return s;
    }
private:
    std::mutex mu;
    std::condition_variable cond;

    std::deque<T> buffer;
};
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problems with `add`:

- the while(true) is useless
- you want to `notify_one`, not `notify_all` because you've only added one thing, and so only one thread waiting to remove can remove it.
- you should overload for two version which take `const T&` and `T&&` (the latter would `std::move`). This would be optimal in all cases. (analogous to `push_back` in standard containers)
- You may also want to add an `emplace` to complement the `add()` versions so you can construct `T` in-place at the top of the Buffer.
- you can use `lock_guard` instead of `unique_lock` and scope it with `{}`s. I'd just say always prefer the lighter weight construct when a heavier weight one isn't strictly needed.

problems with `remove`:

- the `while (true)` is useless
- the cond var lambda can be `return !buffer.empty();`
- the back variable can be `std::move`d
- what happens if you destruct an empty `Buffer` while a thread is waiting on `remove`? That case isn't handled at all, and it's a problem
- there's no reason to `notify_all` in `remove`. Who is it notifying and why?

problems with `size`:

- use a `lock_guard` unless `unique_lock` is *needed*
- just do: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mu}; return buffer.size();`

Comment: Good point about the emplace (emplace_back?). But I don't agree with letting the lock_guard cover the notify as that means the other thread potentially wakes, sees its still locked goes to sleep again, then is re-awakened by the unlock, wasting a lot of cycles.

Comment: I am thinking the same way as @Surt regarding the locking. Actually it  (`unique_lock`) has been taken from C++ documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: @sebap123 you only _need_ that in `remove`. See updated answer

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions and corrections. You are correct with destructing empty `Buffer` while waiting in `remove`. Indeed there is some improvement required.

Comment: @sebap123 one way to handle it would be to return a `std::optional<T>` from `remove` and have an additional mechanism to tell remove to exit and return nullopt

Comment: @David I've read about `std::optional` but unfortunately this is only since C++17, and since I am using up to C++14 I cannot use it. Is there any other solution here?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Wouldn't you need to lock in the destructor too? What happens if one thread calls ~Buffer() and another calls add()?
The add() function would add to a destroyed std::deque.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `std::stack` if you want to push and pop from the back, using FILO. If you mean to use FIFO `std:deque` is the correct choice as it is optimized for back and front access.

As already mentioned the `while` is useless and `notify_all` is probably wrong.

The placement of the `unlock` is good, so that other threads don't wake, see they are still locked, then when you unlock they are awakened again, wasting lots of cycles.

Using unique_lock is an OK choice as it is needed for the `condition_variable` anyway.

Comment: You are correct with my FIFO approach. I just forget to change from my previous FILO solution. Thank you for pointing that out.